# Sequential Criterion for Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove the following:

Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $c\in A$, and $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is continuous at $c$ if and only if for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ such that $(x_n) \to c$, $(f(x_n)) \to f(c)$.

I am using is the usual $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: For example, see this: http://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/334_14/continuity.pdf